# Pause Traktor deck automatically when cue point is reached?

Tags: software, dj, traktor

I have a cue point that marks the point in a track where I want playback to stop on Deck A. Is there a way to "tell" Traktor to pause as soon as this cue point is reached?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that's not possible. You have Cue, Fade-In/Out, Load, Grid, Loop. That's it.